# How to populate client combobox with items from service's list of objects

Tags: c#, wcf

**EDIT**: http://pastebin.com/EVjD95RY

*snippet of service's code*

My Windows Forms WCF client has two combo boxes - combobox1 and combobox2.

My Web Based WCF service has a `List` of objects with information:

```
public List<CompanyInfo> companies = new List<CompanyInfo>();
```

Don't know why `companies` isn't available to me in client. I made the following reference to the service inside client...

```
Client.ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
```

...which should have allowed me to access `comapnies` like so: `client.companies`

A typical object of CompanyInfo has the following data members:

`companyName`, `address`, `type`

Inside my client I made it so when I select an item from combobox1, let's say `Technology`, the combobox2 will become enabled and should populate itself with all of the objects from `companies` that have their `type` data member set to 'technology'.

Problem is I can't figure it out. I am trying to use `foreach` like so:

```
    private void combobox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (combobox1.Text != "")
                {
                    combobox2.Enabled = true;
// For every object inside the companies list that have their type set to technology put them into the combobox, disregards the other types
                    if (combobox1.SelectedText.Equals("Technology"))
                    {

                        foreach(ServiceReference1.CompanyInfo ci in ?)
                        {
                            if(ci.Type.Equals("technology"))
                                combobox2.Items.Add(?);
                        }
                    } // more options i.e. combobox1.SelectedText.Equals("Medicine")
                }
                else
                    combobox2.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your webservice you could create a method GetCompaniesOfType and pass in the selected value. Preferably some kind of ID and not a string value. With the result of that method you can populate your second combobox. If the list of companies does not change a lot you can add client and/or server side caching to load the data faster.

Code would become something like this

```
Private void combobox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    combobox2.Items.Clear();

    if (combobox1.SelectedValue == null)
        return;

    var companies = ServiceReference1.GetCompaniesOfType(combobox1.SelectedValue);
    combobox2.Items.Add(companies);
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting suggestion. But what bothers me is why `companies` `List` isn't visible to me when using `client` reference? I see all the other public methods of the service when I type `client.`

Comment: Ok, then I misinterpreted the question. I guess you should post your service code with the companies instead. Did you make it public with the correct attributes?

Comment: Yep. Right inside the Service : IService class I mention at the top companies like so: public List<CompanyInfo> companies = new List<CompanyInfo>();
Then I use a void function PopulateData() that just creates 3 objects of type CompanyInfo, supply them with appropriate information for data members and then do the `companies.Add(obj1), companies.Add(obj2)` all inside the Service class which implements IService interface. I added a link to pastebin with the code snipped from the service.cs

Comment: Your list of companies should be a property and not a public field. You also need to add the DataContract attribute at class level and a DataMember attribute at the property level.

Comment: Really? Does that mean I have to make another class inside the interface file?

Comment: No, the attributes need to be set in the interface you allready have, maybe you should post it as well.